# ngx-card - card directive fails in angular universal build

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-universal

I have updated the Angular version of my Angular project from 7 to 8. However, during the build with Angular universal, it fails due to the ngx-card plug-in.

- I added "--bundleDependencies all" to the end of "build: client-and-server-bundles" in package.json -> scripts.
- I added the following line in server.ts;
  `const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} = require('./dist/server/main');`
- I added the following lines in the main.server.ts file;
  `export {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';`
  `export {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';`
- I added the following in the webpack.server.config.js file;
  `externals: {
  './dist/server/main': 'require("./dist/server/main")'
  }`

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app-server",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} = require('./dist/server/main');

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
// const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

main.server.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
export {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
export {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
```

webpack.server.config.js

```
// Work around for https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: {
    // This is our Express server for Dynamic universal
    server: './server.ts'
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      {
        // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
        // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
        test: /(\\|\/)@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/).+\.js$/,
        parser: { system: true },
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ],
  externals: {
    './dist/server/main': 'require("./dist/server/main")'
  }
};
```

npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr and result;

```
> node dist/server

C:\Development\git\project\node_modules\ngx-card\card.js:1
import { Directive, Input, ContentChildren, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.ngx-card/card (C:\Development\git\project\dist\dist\server\main.js:30572:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Development\git\project\dist\dist\server\main.js:20:30)
    at Object../src/app/components/account/setup/setup.component.ngfactory.js (C:\Development\git\project\dist\dist\server\main.js:21686:72)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@0.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.0.0 serve:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mehme\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-16T13_07_42_183Z-debug.log
```

Comment: post also your tsconfig.server.json

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example as a repo, otherwise it is hard to reproduce your error. Testing an angular-universal starter (https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter) which uses ng8 togehter with ngx-card works fine for me. Maybe you can compare the configs to find any difference.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi Thank you I made the necessary additions.

Comment: @zerocewl Thank you. I will create a project from scratch and just try it with this plugin.

Comment: try to set in tsconfig.server.json under compilerOptions the module like {
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app-server",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}

Comment: When I created and tried a new project, there was no problem. I tried again using the configuration files in the new project, but it again gave the same error. Then I deleted the add-on tried again gave the same error. So it gives error from the plugin I deleted. Not in a place I use. Interesting.